# kivy: with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') doesn't work

Tags: python, encoding, kivy

my python version is 3.6

If I write korean in .kv file

and typed in python

```
Builder.load_file("Bus_Information.kv")
```

..it didn't working.

and i found the solution like this below

```
with open('Bus_Information.kv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    Builder.load_string(f.read())
```

and there is no more error. but in the screen, there is only broken letters..
[image] like this..

how can i fix this? thank you for reading.

py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.clock import Clock
#from kivy.config import Config
#Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (486, 650) 

class Loading_Screen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Loading_Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.callNext, 2) 
    def callNext(self,dt):
        self.manager.current = 'Before_First_Screen'

class Load_BusInfo():
    pass

class Before_First_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class First_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class Test_Screen(Screen):
    pass

class DTN_TECHNOPARK(Screen): 
    pass

class DTN_BITZONE(Screen): 
    pass

class DTN_INUSTATION(Screen): 
    pass

class Bus_Information(Screen): ####<---Here is the problem.####
    with open('Bus_Information.kv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        Builder.load_string(f.read())
    #Builder.load_file("Bus_Information.kv")

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class TubucApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

TubucApp().run()
```

This is .kv file

```
<Bus_Information>:
    name: 'Bus_Information'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size 
            source: 'image/destination/a.png' #backgroundimage
    Label:
        text_size: cm(6), cm(4)
        #halign: 'right'                
        #valign: 'middle'           
        pos: [1, 1]
        id: my_custom_label
        text: '가나다라마바사' ##here is broken letters..##
        color: [255,255,255,1]
```

i tried

1. `u'가나다라마바사'`
2. `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: Is the text `utf-8`? Also: not all fonts support all characters... so even if the encoding is correct you may have to choose a font that support that text.

Comment: I changed the font and it was fixed. Thank you for your advice!